# Using on click vanilla JS, activating on wrong node

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

Almost finished this sort of game i am working on to learn Dom manipulation. Basically the game spawns 5 images on the left and 4 on the right, you click the odd one out and then 10 spawn on the left and 9 on the right(+5 everytime).

I am wanting my nextlevel function to work every time the last child(of theLeftSide) is clicked on. It works the first time but after that regardless of if i click the correct node or not, my gameOver function is called and im not sure why. I tried removing the game over function and still the 2nd time i want my nextLevel to run(after click), it doesnt. Am i going about this the totally wrong way? Any input is appreciated thank you. Left my gameOver function in so you can see what im trying to do with it.

```js
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftside");
var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightside");
var facesNeeded = 5;
var totalfFaces = 0;
var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

function makeFaces() {
  while (facesNeeded != totalfFaces) {
    smiley = document.createElement("img");
    smiley.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
    smiley.style.top = Math.random() * 401 + "px";
    smiley.style.left = Math.random() * 401 + "px";
    document.getElementById("leftside").appendChild(smiley);
    totalfFaces++;
    // alert(totalfFaces); used to debug
  }
  if (facesNeeded == totalfFaces) {
    //alert(facesNeeded);
    //alert(totalfFaces);
    leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
    leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
    document.getElementById("rightside").appendChild(leftSideImages);
    //alert("hi");
  }
}

makeFaces();

function delFaces(side) {
  while (side.firstChild) {
    side.removeChild(side.firstChild);
  }

}

theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  delFaces(theRightSide);
  delFaces(theLeftSide);
  totalfFaces = 0;
  facesNeeded += 5;
  //alert(facesNeeded);
  //alert(totalfFaces);
  makeFaces();

};

theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
  alert("Game Over!");
  theBody.onclick = null;
  theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      position: absolute;
    }
    div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    #rightside {
      left: 500px;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1> Matching Game</h1>
  <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
  <div id="leftside"></div>
  <div id="rightside"></div>
  <script src="script3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move the `onclick` inside the `makeFaces` after the `while`, so its added everytime after it creates them all:-

```js
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftside");
var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightside");
var facesNeeded = 5;
var totalfFaces = 0;
var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

function makeFaces() {
  while (facesNeeded != totalfFaces) {
    smiley = document.createElement("img");
    smiley.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
    smiley.style.top = Math.random() * 401 + "px";
    smiley.style.left = Math.random() * 401 + "px";
    document.getElementById("leftside").appendChild(smiley);
    totalfFaces++;
    // alert(totalfFaces); used to debug
  }
  if (facesNeeded == totalfFaces) {
    //alert(facesNeeded);
    //alert(totalfFaces);
    leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
    leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
    document.getElementById("rightside").appendChild(leftSideImages);
    //alert("hi");
  }
  theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     delFaces(theRightSide);
     delFaces(theLeftSide);
     totalfFaces = 0;
     facesNeeded += 5;
     //alert(facesNeeded);
     //alert(totalfFaces);
     makeFaces();

   };
}

makeFaces();

function delFaces(side) {
  while (side.firstChild) {
    side.removeChild(side.firstChild);
  }

}

theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
  alert("Game Over!");
  theBody.onclick = null;
  theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      position: absolute;
    }
    div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    #rightside {
      left: 500px;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1> Matching Game</h1>
  <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left</p>
  <div id="leftside"></div>
  <div id="rightside"></div>
  <script src="script3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I guess this is what happens when i code late into the night. Silly mistake, Thank you so much.